# Data tables not being created when deploying MVC4 to Azurewebsites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, unit-of-work

So after many many hours of figuring out why my database tables weren't being created when deploying to azure(using mvc4 code first entity framework), I finally came figured out that its the way I have my backend set up. I have my generic repository, unit of work, datacontext, etc..(which is not causing the problem). Whats causing my data tables(500 server error) not to create is my UnitOfWorkFilter. When I apply this it doesn't work, when I take away it works. So my question is does anybody know why this is causing the problem and what I can do to fix this problem because I would like to continue to use my filter.

Here is my unit of work filter:

```
    public class UnitOfWorkFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var unitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();

        unitOfWork.Begin();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var unitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            unitOfWork.Rollback();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            unitOfWork.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            unitOfWork.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: YOu can add a startup.cmd and the following to get better errors %windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe -section:system.webServer/httpErrors -errorMode:Detailed see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154098.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Trace statements so you can see what's going on in Azure. Set up Trace with the following code:

```
private void ConfigDiagnostics()
{
    DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = 
        DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
    config.ConfigurationChangePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);
    config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 500;
    config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
    config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);

    DiagnosticMonitor.Start(
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", 
        config);
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what this does or how it works. This unitofworkfilter works find on my local database so i can't really debug locally. It only not works when I use with azure databases. Is this something that can used as a published project? Thanks for input btw.

Comment: The code above enables tracing so you can get trace output local or on Azure. See my blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/10/25/using-trace-in-windows-azure-cloud-applications-1.aspx